# NodeJS return data from for() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

> This might be a very basic question but I've never done it and I can't
> make it so far, so I'm gonna asking it here!

I have a function in separate `js` file and it supposed to return messages from for loop data but not sure where the `return` has to go!

this is my code:

```
function test(x,y) {
    for(let i in y) {
        if(y[i].value == 'x') {
            return bot.message(y[i]);
        }
        sleep(1500);
    }
}
```

this doesn't return anything.

So what I'm trying to do here is to send multiple messages from my loop and put 1.5 seconds sleep between each message.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you also provide some input data upon which to test this function?

Comment: The parameter `x` is unused, is it supposed to be `not used`?

Comment: `sleep` isn't a standard function? What package are you using for that?

Comment: @NalinRanjan 1- `const y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` `const x = 'a'` 2- `y[i].value == 'x'` X used 3- sleep my other function in this file `function sleep(ms) {return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));}`

Comment: if `y` is an `string[]`, then we will not have `y[i].value` ?

Comment: `const y = [{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value:'c'}];` problem solved?

Comment: Thanks.. Now the other problem is the usage of parameter `x`. `'x'` is a string with value `x` and not the argument of x itself. Can you edit that as well please? Because if I run the function as is in the OP, over the `y` which you have given, there will never be a match.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this...

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const bot = {
    message: (value) => {
        console.log('[Bot]', '[Received]', value);
    }
};
async function test(x, y) {
    for (let i in y) {
        if (y[i].value === x) {
            bot.message(y[i]);
        }
        await sleep(1500);
        console.log('Woke Up!!!');
    }
}
const y = [{ value: 'a' }, { value: 'b' }, { value: 'a' }];
const x = 'a';
test(x, y);
```

Of course, imagination involved.